# proguard make apk complete and make dump,mapping,seed but not obfuscating

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apk, proguard

Eclipse version

1. I use proguard so  ouput dump.txt mapping.txt seeds.txt
2. make APK project name -> Export -> Android -> export singned Android
   application
3. output apk -> decomplie but not obfuscating

why not obfuscating ? Let me know

**source**

**project.properties**

proguard.config=proguard.cfg

**proguard.cfg**

```
# This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html


-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

# Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
# through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
# of these optimizations on its own).
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
# Note that if you want to enable optimization, you cannot just
# include optimization flags in your own project configuration file;
# instead you will need to point to the
# "proguard-android-optimize.txt" file instead of this one from your
# project.properties file.

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}

# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**

# Understand the @Keep support annotation.
-keep class android.support.annotation.Keep

-keep @android.support.annotation.Keep class * {*;}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep <init>(...);
}



-allowaccessmodification 
-repackageclasses ""



-dontshrink

# Retain declared checked exceptions for use by a Proxy instance.
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry

 

#################################################################################################
# My Code
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-dontwarn org.apache.**
```

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is still using ADT instead of Gradle to export Android applications. You can use Gradle from within Eclipse as I have described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47112271/5981535